# Displaying back on scroll up an object hidden on scroll down

Tags: javascript

I've been successful on hiding a div on scroll, but I thought the code would display the div back again on scrolling back, but it does not. How can I do that?

```html
<body>
  <div class="imagem-capa">
    <img src="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/images/full/apple_158989157.jpg"></div>
  <div class="random"></div>
<script src="pen.js"></script>
</body>
```

```css
.random {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.imagem-capa img {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```js
let capa = document.getElementsByClassName("imagem-capa");
console.log(capa);

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  let scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

  if (scrollPosition <= 50) {
    capa[0].style.display = 'block' - scrollPosition / 50;
  } else {
    capa[0].style.display = 'none'  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you made mistake in your js code, remove  `- scrollPosition / 50`.

```
 if (scrollPosition <= 50) {
capa[0].style.display = 'block';
} else {
 capa[0].style.display = 'none'  
}
```

Comment: Hi Nazir, thank you for your reply. 

Without that part of code, the result on my mobile browser and desktop browser is that when I achieve the scroll trigger the capa object goes on a loop of block/hide, flickering on the screen.